# dhtmlXCalendar Start and End date limit

Tags: jquery-ui, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlXCalendar to create my calendar.

Is it possible to have a Start and End date limit to it so a user can cannot choose a date prior or beyond to a certain dates.

I want use to selected dates only between today and 2 years from today.

Any advice

Thanks 
FArid

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using the `setSensitiveRange()` [method](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxcalendar_setsensitiverange.html) Here is a simple example

```
<script>
        var myCalendar;
        function doOnLoad() {
            myCalendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject("calendarHere");
            myCalendar.hideTime();
            myCalendar.show();
            myCalendar.setDate("2017-09-22");
            myCalendar.setSensitiveRange("2017-09-22","2019-09-22");
        }
</script>
```